# Using RelativeLayout instead of Nested Weights

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-layout-weight

I've been working on a simple soundboard app. The basic design is an imageview for the title, followed by 4 rows of buttons (3 in each row), which makes it look similar to an old cellphone's buttons. At the bottom, there is a "random" and "stop" button. They take up slightly less height space than the rows mentioned above, but the random button was double the width to fill up the space.

To achieve this look, I have been using nested weights and linear layouts. However, upon further research, I have found that this is bad for performance because in my current format, each item is being measured 8 times. My XML layout code is below. I have excluded a lot of UI modifiers such as margins, text, and shadows on the buttons to make the code smaller. The code may seem long, but it is repetitive and simple to understand.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="23" >

<!-- Insert Title/Picture in Linear Layout below -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:background="@drawable/etho_logo"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Insert Sounds/Buttons in Linear Layout below -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <!-- This is the 1st line of buttons -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This is the 2nd line of buttons -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This is the 3rd line of buttons -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This is the 4th line of buttons -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Random Button and Stop button below here -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bIntro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bIntro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am new to Android, so even though I have tried using a Relative layout, I have had an extremely hard time working with it. I tried watching tutorials online, but still it never looked right when I used it in my code.

For example, my title image has extra space above and below the actual text I want to display. In Linear Layout with weights, it would automatically become smaller to fit the space I gave it. Not in RelativeLayout though.

I guess what I'm trying to ask here is: How do I make it so my RelativeLayout items are evenly spaced buttons across a few rows (as shown in example above), and how do I make it so ImageViews and other things actually automatically size down to the space I give them? If any more information is needed, please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that `RelativeLayout` is difficult to make into tables such as the one you made above.  `LinearLayout` is really ideal for that, which is why the `TableLayout` and `TableRow` view groups are subclasses of `LinearLayout`.  I can recommend a couple of alternatives besides `RelativeLayout` that will increase layout efficiency, however.

First, you can eliminate the second vertically oriented `LinearLayout` and change the layout weight of the first 4 rows of buttons from 1 to 1.25.  This will reduce the number of layout passes from 8 to 4, which is the best you can do for a table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="23" >

    <!-- Insert Title/Picture in Linear Layout below -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:background="@drawable/etho_logo"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This is the 1st line of buttons -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <!-- 3 buttons here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This is the 2nd line of buttons -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <!-- 3 buttons here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This is the 3rd line of buttons -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <!-- 3 buttons here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This is the 4th line of buttons -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <!-- 3 buttons here -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Random Button and Stop button below here -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bIntro"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/hello_real_select" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Another option is to use a single layout that makes a "flat" grid (a `ViewGroup` that manages the layout of its children into a table by itself).  If you are targeting API level 14+ for your app, you can look at [`GridLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).  If you are targeting an API level prior to 14, you might have to make your own.  On a final note, please do not confuse `GridLayout` with the [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) view group, which is meant to be used with lists and will not accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response and actually including examples of how to fix my code. This was very helpful for me. I had actually decided against using RelativeLayout shortly after posting the question, so your response with optimization techniques for the original code was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use widths of 0dp with weight, which should reduce by half the number of measurements (as the wrap_content require a measurement, but 0dp doesn't)

Also, you don't need the imbricated vertical linear layout, as it is already in a linear layout (although it is cleaner for readability, you can remove it for optimization and adjust the weights)